# Setting requirements for class variables in Swift

Tags: swift, class, initialization, instance-variables

I am new to swift. In a group of classes / subclasses, I would like a variable in the super class to be within a required range.  For example, in the following code.

```
class Vehicle {
    var speed: Int
    var heading: Int

    init(speed: Int, heading: Int) {
        self.speed = speed
        self.heading = heading
    }

    func turnRight() {
        if 360 - heading < 90 {
            heading = heading - 270
        } else {
            heading = heading + 90
        }
    }
}

class Car : Vehicle {
    init(speed: Int, heading: Int) {
        super.init(speed: speed, heading: heading)
    }

    override func turnRight() {
        speed = speed / 2
        if 360 - heading < 90 {
            heading = heading - 270
        } else {
            heading = heading + 90
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't like about the above, is that if I'm creating more subclasses for car, I'll always be forced to check that heading is within 0 and 360.  I know about getters and setters, but is there a way to use a setter and still support incrementing the variable?

Ideally, I want my turnRight functions to look like:

```
func turnRight() {
    heading = heading + 90
}

override func turnRight() {
    speed = speed / 2
    heading = heading + 90
}
```

...and for my variable set in the superclass to ensure that the heading is within 0 and 360.

Comment: Well, you could create a function called changeHeadingBy with a float as a parameter then just call this function instead of checking your bearing every time. Then use this instead of your "addition" in the 2nd example.

Comment: Why don't you just call `super.turnRight()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about move heading logic into separate structure?

Demo code is shown above.

```
struct Heading {

    private var heading = 0
    init(initialHeading: Int) {
        heading = initialHeading
    }
    mutating func turnRight(){
        if 360 - heading < 90 {
            heading = heading - 270
        } else {
            heading = heading + 90
        }
    }
}

class Vehicle {
    var speed: Int
    var heading: Heading

    init(speed: Int, heading: Int) {
        self.speed = speed
        self.heading = Heading(initialHeading: heading)
    }

    func turnRight() {
        heading.turnRight()
    }
}

class Car : Vehicle {
    override init(speed: Int, heading: Int) {
        super.init(speed: speed, heading: heading)
    }

    override func turnRight() {
        speed = speed / 2
        super.turnRight()
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Update new solution with typealias and generic function turn by angle and enum values**

```
typealias Angle = Int

enum Direction: Angle {
    case left = -90
    case right = 90 }

struct Heading {

    private var heading : Angle
    init(initialHeading: Angle) {
        heading = initialHeading
    }

    mutating func turnBy(angle: Angle){
        if 360 - heading < angle {
            heading = heading - (360 - angle)
        } else {
            heading = heading + angle
        }
    } 
}

class Vehicle {
    var speed: Int
    var heading: Heading

    init(speed: Int, heading: Int) {
        self.speed = speed
        self.heading = Heading(initialHeading: heading)
    }

    func turnRight() {
        heading.turnBy(angle: Direction.right.rawValue)
    } 
}

class Car : Vehicle {
    override init(speed: Int, heading: Int) {
        super.init(speed: speed, heading: heading)
    }

    override func turnRight() {
        super.turnRight()
        speed = speed / 2
    } 
}
```

Comment: I would also change the `turnRight` to `turn(angle:)` but using a structure is a very nice idea.

Comment: @Sulthan Thank for idea. I just updated original response with new code with this function and enup and typealias

Comment: very nice - I haven't really started using structs yet (I know they're a big part of Swift and I know a small bit of C++ so I have some familiarity).  But, it seems like a pretty self explanatory data structure and works great for my use case.  Thanks!

Comment: @OliPlunkett I'm glad that I can help. Swift structures are really huge part of swift programming. Mostly because their are value type instead of reference type like classes are.

Answer (score 1):

While the implementation in `Vehicle` could be simpler, instead of repeating the implementation you can simply call the original implementation:

```
override func turnRight() {
    speed = speed / 2
    super.turnRight()
}
```

For a simpler implementation, we can, for example:

```
var heading: Int {
    didSet {
        if heading < 0 {
            heading = heading % 360 + 360
        } else {
            heading = heading % 360
        }
    }
}
```

Then turning can be done just using `self.heading += 90`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `didSet` on `heading`

```
class Vehicle {
    var speed: Int
    var heading: Int {
        didSet { 
            if heading > 360 {
                heading -= 360
            } else if heading < 0{
                heading += 360
            }
        }
    }

    init(speed: Int, heading: Int) {
        self.speed = speed
        self.heading = heading
    }

    func turnRight() {
        heading += 90
    }
}

class Car : Vehicle {
    init(speed: Int, heading: Int) {
        super.init(speed: speed, heading: heading)
    }

    override func turnRight() {
        speed = speed / 2
        super.turnRight()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a minor point, setting `heading` to `720` won't keep it in interval `0..360` :)

Comment: _"Answer in haste, repent at leisure!"_

Comment: Thanks!  I came across didSet, but for some reason didn't think it would work in this case.  Glad to see it does :)